# What system environment stores the value of InetAddress.getLocalHost().GetCanonicalHostName()

Tags: java, spring, windows, environment-variables, localhost

I try to understand which system variables has this value. I execute this code and get *some_string*.

> InetAddress.getLocalHost().GetCanonicalHostName();

After this I print all my system env

> System.getenv().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("K = " + k + "
> V = " + v));

I find all variables which has *some_string*, and replace all value with

> ```
> @ClassRule
> public final static EnvironmentVariables ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES = new EnvironmentVariables();
> ```

> ```
> final String pcNameForEnv = "test-pc-name";
> ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.set("USERDOMAIN", pcNameForEnv);
> ```

But my test failed

> ```
> @Test
> public void getMachineNameFromEnv() {
>     final String pcNameForEnv = "test-pc-name";
>     ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.set("USERDOMAIN", pcNameForEnv);
>
>     final String machineName = networkUtil.getPCNetworkName();
>
>     assertEquals(pcNameForEnv, machineName);
> }
> ```

I finded that I need replace this ver:

> "user.name",
> "user.home",
> "LOGONSERVER",
> "COMPUTERNAME",
> "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE",
> "USERDOMAIN",
> "COMPUTERNAME",
> "MACHINENAME";

But it don't help me too.

Comment: What are you trying to do that led you down this path?

Comment: The hostname is not stored in an environment variable. On most systems the most likely source of that information is the DNS (domain name system) service. It might also be retrieved from the file */etc/hosts* or some other OS specific mechanism. So changing the hostname depends on your OS and how it is configured.

Comment: I try to write unit test. I get some "computer id" for identify it in company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set an environment variable to make Java think you are on a different machine.  From [java.lang.InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()) -

> Returns the address of the local host. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.